# how to change values with rank value (ordered value) in R? and I want to give same numbers when two values tie

Tags: r, ranking

My data has an ID column and I want to rename ID as an rank. In other words I want to rename all 35-> 1, all 39->2, all 66 ->3 all 77-> 4 and all 90 -> 5 from below data. 
I tried to use rank function but I could not deal with two tied value. I want to give same number for two tied value in id (e.g. all 35 get 1).
How can I change each id as an ascending order number?

```
ID
--
35
35
35
35
39
39
39
66
66
66
66
77
77
90
90
90
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that factor variables assign sequential values starting from 1 to your sorted data:

```
ID <- c(35, 35, 35, 35, 39, 39, 39, 66, 66, 66, 66, 77, 77, 90, 90, 90)
as.numeric(as.factor(ID))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5
```

This also turns out to be much faster than the other proposed approaches (even after factoring the `unique(vect)` out of Vincent's `sapply` function):

```
library(microbenchmark)
ID <- rnorm(10000)
microbenchmark(as.numeric(as.factor(ID)), funPascal(ID), funVincent(ID))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                       expr        min         lq     median        uq         max neval
#  as.numeric(as.factor(ID))   23.94388   24.64445   25.17679   25.8263    34.68806   100
#              funPascal(ID) 2754.19694 2822.37356 2875.71998 2929.9071  3471.90363   100
#             funVincent(ID)  416.58985  438.13800  445.29766  458.8043   769.44278   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, using `recodeVar{doBy}`:

```
library(doBy)
ID <- c(35, 35, 35, 35, 39, 39, 39, 66, 66, 66, 66, 77, 77, 90, 90, 90)
src <- unique(sort(ID))
tgt <- seq_along(src)
ID <- recodeVar(ID, src, tgt)
ID
[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, josilber's solution works very well and simplier than what I'll propose. However, the use of `sapply` (or another `apply`-like function) is a more general answer to the 'how to transform a vector' issue. In your case, the following returns what you want :

```
vect<-c(2,2,3,5,5,6,8)
sapply(1:length(vect),FUN=function (i) 1+sum(unique(vect)<vect[i]))
[1] 1 1 2 3 3 4 5
```

You might want to remember that function, which is very useful as soon as you go for complex data manipulation.

Comment: Right now you're computing `unique(vect)` for every index, which makes your whole operation O(n^2) instead of O(n). You should precompute `unique(vect)` before running `sapply`.

Comment: @josilber You're right. However, this answer was not really intended to be used in this particular case, your solution being way simpler. I just wanted to show how `sapply` can deal with that kind of questions, when no useful trick like the one you found is available. Adding more stuff would be harmful to this purpose and wouldn't even make it faster than your suggestion.